# How to set null in decimal type in mysql through JDBC on google apps script

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc, mysql-workbench

I am working on Google Apps Script and using JDBC.
I am trying to set `null` for a column whose sql type is `decimal`.
I am using `prepareStatement` to execute the insert.

The column setting on mysql workbench:

[image]

I want the result to look like:

[image: image for null on mysql workbench]

I tried it using `stmt.setNull(3, 0);` and `stmt.setNull(3, 8);` But both of the results look like:

[image]

I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: What do you think `setNull(3,0)` does? The second parameter of [`setNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull(int,int)) expects a value of `java.sql.Types`, eg `java.sql.Types.DECIMAL` (which has value `3`), `0` is `Types.NULL` and `8` is `Types.DOUBLE`, which possibly may not work correctly when trying to null a column of type `DECIMAL`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for your comment. I just checked it one more time and then found setNull(3,0) set null successfully as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for posting this question. I found that I made a mistake on original testing. I tried to test `stmt.setNull(3, 0)` but actually program executed `stmt.setNull(3, 8)`. And I took the `0.00` as the result. But it was mistake.

I changed the code to make sure `stmt.setNull(3, 0);` would be executed. And I found:

`stmt.setNull(3, 0);` set null successfully as the image below.

[image]

specification for `setNull(parameterIndex, sqlType)`

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-prepared-statement#setNull(Integer,Integer)

when you want to set `sqlType` to `null`, you should set `0`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.NULL

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's issue, it is better to add context, or an explanation as to why this solves the OP's problem, so future visitors can learn from your post, and apply this knowledge to their own issues. High Quality Answers are much more likely to be upvoted, and contribute to the value and quality of SO as a platform. You can also add a link to documentation, if that helps.